# Defining an explict structure

Tags: order-theory, model-theory

Is that possible to define an explict structure $\mathfrak{A}$ such that $\mathfrak{A}$ is a substructure of $\mathfrak{B}$ which $\mathfrak{A}$ is isomorphic to the natural numbers $\mathfrak{N} = (\mathbb{N},0,S,+,\cdot,E,<)$.

Where $\mathfrak{B} \vDash N$ where $N = \{ N_1, ..., N_{11} \}$.

\begin{align*}
&~\hspace{10mm} \mathbf{The~Axioms~of~}N \\
&N_1.~(\forall x) \neg S x = 0. \\
&N_2.~(\forall x)(\forall y) [S x = S y \rightarrow x = y]. \\
&N_3.~(\forall x) x + 0 = x. \\
&N_4.~(\forall x)(\forall y) x + S y = S(x + y). \\
&N_5.~(\forall x) x \cdot 0 = 0. \\
&N_6.~(\forall x)(\forall y) x \cdot S y = (x \cdot y) + x. \\
&N_7.~(\forall x) x E 0 = S 0. \\
&N_8.~(\forall x)(\forall y) x E (S y) = (x E y) \cdot x. \\
&N_9.~(\forall x) \neg x < 0. \\
&N_{10}.~(\forall x)(\forall y) [x < S y \leftrightarrow (x < y \vee x = y)]. \\
&N_{11}.~(\forall x)(\forall y) [(x < y) \vee (x = y) \vee (y < x)]. 
\end{align*}

Well, I am quite stuck in the beginning. It is even hard for me to imagine what will $\mathfrak{B}$ would be like and I know that $\mathfrak{B}$ cannot be exactly same as $\mathfrak{N}$ since, $\mathfrak{N}$ does not have a proper substructure. So, is that possible to define an explict structure $\mathfrak{A}$ such that $\mathfrak{A}$ is a substructure of $\mathfrak{B}$ which $\mathfrak{A}$ is isomorphic to the natural numbers $\mathfrak{N} = (\mathbb{N},0,S,+,\cdot,E,<)$.

Comment: I swear you already asked and deleted this exact same question and I told you in the comments that the substructure generated by $0$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak N$, so I’ll say it again here. Also, $\mathfrak B$ can totally be the same thing as $\mathfrak N$... $\mathfrak N\models N$, doesn’t it? In this case the substructure isomorphic to $\mathfrak N$ will just be itself. Of course the case where $\mathfrak B$ is not isomorphic to $\mathfrak N$ is the nontrivial one.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I am so Sorry, I think I didn't see any comment in the prev one so I just delete that question.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I don't quite get the part of $\mathfrak{B}$ can totally be the same thing as $\mathfrak{N}...\mathfrak{N} \vDash N$, becasue then in this case $\mathfrak{A}$ would be a substructure of $\mathfrak{N}$ but then $\mathfrak{N}$ does not have a proper substructure. So $\mathfrak{A}$ cannot be a substructure of $\mathfrak{N}$ isn't it ?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Also the substructure generated by 0 is $(\{ 0 \}, 0, +, \cdot)$ right ?

Comment: $\mathfrak A=\mathfrak N$... it is a substructure but not a proper substructure. (BTW understanding *why* $\mathfrak N$ has no proper substructure may help here, cause the reason is essentially that $\mathfrak N$ is generated by $0$.)

Comment: No, that is not closed under the successor function.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen So, are you saying that I can let $\mathfrak{B}=(\mathbb{N},0,S,+,⋅,E,<)$ and $\mathfrak{A}=(\mathbb{N},0,S,+,⋅,E,<)$which $\mathfrak{A}$ substructure of $\mathfrak{B}$ and $\mathfrak{A}$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{N}$ right ?

Comment: Yes... which keep in mind is just a trivial case here. You still need to show an arbitrary model of N has a substructure isomorphic to the naturals. All I was saying is that the naturals are a model of N and they trivially have a substructure isomorphic to the naturals, which accords with the theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I have a basic idea to prove the prev question.